# SUMPRODUCT to count multiple cells in multiple columns with multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets, sumproduct

I need some help here, I have a table where I need to count the number of cells containing the word "Late" and all blank cells.

I am using this formula:
=Sumproduct("$C$17:$AF$30"={"","Late"})

[Here the sample of my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzQxE.png)

Comment: Try `COUNTIF()`.. does it solves in you case?

Comment: yeah, that works, but that is just a part of a whole formula. the formula consists of multiple criteria both horizontal and vertical that countifs can't handle. That's why I am using sumproduct

Comment: Example `countif` [with horizontal and vertical criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68002825/7602468) What is the criteria?

Comment: Heres the full formula that I am working on right now:
=sumproduct((Sheet1!$A$17:$A$30=index(HC!$M$4:$M$16,match(A126,HC!$L$4:$L$16,0)))*(Sheet1!$C$17:$AF$30="")*(Sheet1!$C$3:$AF$3>=HC!$M$17)*(Sheet1!$C$3:$AF$3")<=today()))

The criterias that I need are Name, date, and the ones that I have mentioned above.

Comment: I need to count the cells in Sheet1!$A$17:$A$30 depending on name (which is on the left side) date range (above) and if the contains Late or blank cells

Comment: Seems like the 'Name' is always the same value.. I cannot see/map the formula on the screenshot you've shared.. any sample/detail perhaps?

Comment: Here's the sample of the table https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b8N45qZaU3HOBVqskd2dNMzB0Bxx6BIM-JSe9oyiyXs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: (There is no `HC` Sheet in the file) may I know what `(Sheet1!$A$17:$A$30=index(HC!$M$4:$M$16,match(A126,HC!$L$4:$L$16,0)))` look for ? What is the value in `HC!$M$17` ?

Comment: I left some comments on the sheet itself,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to the link in the comment, but plus a twist (to count the blank).

total = a + b

where a = number of "Late" with the defined criteria
b = number of blank

a is `=countif(offset($C$3,match($V29,$B$3:$B$13,0)-1,0,1,(today()-HC!$M$17)+1),"Late")`

b is `=COUNTBLANK(offset($C$3,match($V29,$B$3:$B$13,0)-1,0,1,(today()-HC!$M$17)+1))`

Idea: use `match()` to get the criteria `today()-ref` to get the width, to adjust the `count/countblank` range.